# How to prove that for any factorial of a number greater than one its result is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm having trouble finding a way to prove with induction that, given $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n>1$ then $n! = k\times2$ where $k=(n-1)*(n-2)…$.

Comment: I think you mean $n!=k\cdot n$?

Comment: @DonThousand I think not. I want to prove that the result is even, so (I think) $n! = (n-1)*(n-2)… 2$. As any factorial will end up multiplied by 2, it makes the result even. The problem is that I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: base case:  $2!=2$ is even; for the inductive step, remember that $(m+1)!=(m+1)m!$, and the product of an even number and another number is even

Comment: Note that given a prime $p$ we have that $n!$ is divisible by $p$ for $n\ge p$. Once you can see how this works for $2$ you should be able to test your understanding with $3, 5, 7$ etc

Comment: It could be even faster depending on how you define factorial.  One of the available definitions is $n! = \prod\limits_{k=1}^n k$ which noting that for $n\geq 2$ could be factored as $n! = \prod\limits_{k=1}^n k = 2\times \prod\limits_{k=3}^n$ by just removing the first two terms from the product, a way of formalizing the "end up multiplied by 2" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is answered correctly in comments.

A more interesting question is  to find a formula for the pattern of the powers of $2$ in $n!$

Starting with $2!$ the pattern is $$\{ 1,1,3,3,4,4,7,7,8,8,10,.....\}$$